# WYSIWYG editor opens when edit products

Tags: products, wysiwyg

In the configuration I've enabled the editor: Enable WYSIWYG Editor = "Enabled by Default"
Is it possible, that the Editor is open when I start edit products without click on the button and open it in the box?

Answer (score 2):

When you have the admin configuration setting: System -> Configuration -> Content Management -> Enable WYSIWYG Editor = Enabled by Default
This will enable the Show/Hide Editor toggle to be active by default when you are editing CMS pages and Static blocks. This setting does not effect the product editing screen.

If you want the WYSIWYG editor to open up automatically on page load for product editing (i.e. Short Description) you would need some custom javascript to 'click' the button on page load.  This would be an edit to the admin panel js of Magento and would most likely not be recommended.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I saw editor extensions where the editor was always visible. Have anyone an idea how to edit the code, to show the editor without click?